# Heroku Go WebApp Error – Connection Closed Without Response

Tags: postgresql, http, go, heroku

I’m trying to deploy a Golang app in Heroku. I’m getting a H13 error and I don’t know how to fix it.

The app queries a database and returns a table of results. The database is small, the query is small. It runs locally on port 8080, no problem at all.

The [H13 Error documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes#h13-connection-closed-without-response) says that

> This error is thrown when a process in your web dyno accepts a
>   connection, but then closes the socket without writing anything to it.
>
> One example where this might happen is when a Unicorn web server is
>   configured with a timeout shorter than 30s and a request has not been
>   processed by a worker before the timeout happens. In this case,
>   Unicorn closes the connection before any data is written, resulting in
>   an H13.

I’m not running a Unicorn web server as far as I know (although I am outside my comfort zone in having to configure servers in first place). I am running the app from the vanilla `net/http` package - there are no routing add-ons or anything like that. I did some googling and tried extending the timeout time, like this:

```golang
s := &http.Server{
    Addr: ":8080",
    ReadTimeout:  5 * time.Second,
    WriteTimeout: 10 * time.Second,
    IdleTimeout:  120 * time.Second,
}


if  len(os.Getenv("PORT")) > 0 {
    s := &http.Server{
        Addr: ":" + os.Getenv("PORT"),
        ReadTimeout:  50 * time.Second,
        WriteTimeout: 100 * time.Second,
        IdleTimeout:  1200 * time.Second,
    }
    log.Fatal(s.ListenAndServe())
        } 

log.Fatal(s.ListenAndServe())
```

`ListenAndServe()` is normally called on the `http` object. Here, I've created a server object and given it massively-extended timeouts and then called `ListenAndServe()` on that, but I made no progress. It's the same `H13` error all the time.

These are the error logs:

```
2020-01-06T18:46:20.771328+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Unidling
2020-01-06T18:46:20.776052+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to starting
2020-01-06T18:46:21.616792+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/gowebappdatabase`
2020-01-06T18:46:24.357786+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2020-01-06T18:46:24.284251+00:00 app[web.1]: Incipio - I begin.
2020-01-06T18:46:25.826969+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020/01/06 18:46:25 http: panic serving 10.71.246.139:27839: dial tcp: lookup port=0: no such host
2020-01-06T18:46:25.827017+00:00 app[web.1]: goroutine 20 [running]:
2020-01-06T18:46:25.827020+00:00 app[web.1]: net/http.(*conn).serve.func1(0xc0001100a0)
2020-01-06T18:46:25.827022+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/tmp/cache/go1.12.12/go/src/net/http/server.go:1769 +0x139
2020-01-06T18:46:25.827024+00:00 app[web.1]: panic(0x7e4280, 0xc00010e320)
2020-01-06T18:46:25.827026+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/tmp/cache/go1.12.12/go/src/runtime/panic.go:522 +0x1b5
2020-01-06T18:46:25.827028+00:00 app[web.1]: github.com/amunnelly/gowebappdatabase/dbconnect.runQuery(0xc000150160, 0x150, 0x0)
2020-01-06T18:46:25.827031+00:00 app[web.1]: /tmp/build_b7c9c282f9c067c1b5b5cede1994472d/dbconnect/connectdb.go:78 +0xff
2020-01-06T18:46:25.827033+00:00 app[web.1]: github.com/amunnelly/gowebappdatabase/dbconnect.PointsGdTableQuery(0xc000150160, 0x150, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
2020-01-06T18:46:25.827035+00:00 app[web.1]: /tmp/build_b7c9c282f9c067c1b5b5cede1994472d/dbconnect/connectdb.go:161 +0x64
2020-01-06T18:46:25.827037+00:00 app[web.1]: github.com/amunnelly/gowebappdatabase/routing.ServeHome(0x8db260, 0xc00013a000, 0xc000124100)
2020-01-06T18:46:25.827039+00:00 app[web.1]: /tmp/build_b7c9c282f9c067c1b5b5cede1994472d/routing/routing.go:35 +0x1b5
2020-01-06T18:46:25.827041+00:00 app[web.1]: net/http.HandlerFunc.ServeHTTP(0x863ca0, 0x8db260, 0xc00013a000, 0xc000124100)
2020-01-06T18:46:25.827043+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/tmp/cache/go1.12.12/go/src/net/http/server.go:1995 +0x44
2020-01-06T18:46:25.827045+00:00 app[web.1]: net/http.(*ServeMux).ServeHTTP(0xba17c0, 0x8db260, 0xc00013a000, 0xc000124100)
2020-01-06T18:46:25.827047+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/tmp/cache/go1.12.12/go/src/net/http/server.go:2375 +0x1d6
2020-01-06T18:46:25.827049+00:00 app[web.1]: net/http.serverHandler.ServeHTTP(0xc000086c30, 0x8db260, 0xc00013a000, 0xc000124100)
2020-01-06T18:46:25.827051+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/tmp/cache/go1.12.12/go/src/net/http/server.go:2774 +0xa8
2020-01-06T18:46:25.827053+00:00 app[web.1]: net/http.(*conn).serve(0xc0001100a0, 0x8dbc20, 0xc000118180)
2020-01-06T18:46:25.827055+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/tmp/cache/go1.12.12/go/src/net/http/server.go:1878 +0x851
2020-01-06T18:46:25.827056+00:00 app[web.1]: created by net/http.(*Server).Serve
2020-01-06T18:46:25.827058+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/tmp/cache/go1.12.12/go/src/net/http/server.go:2884 +0x2f4
2020-01-06T18:46:25.828262+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response" method=GET path="/" host=gowebappdatabase.herokuapp.com request_id=b57f171c-5a63-4f2b-b54c-444d7c46d871 fwd="176.61.86.66" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=6ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2020-01-06T18:46:26.697559+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020/01/06 18:46:26 http: panic serving 10.67.225.150:14843: dial tcp: lookup port=0: no such host
2020-01-06T18:46:26.697582+00:00 app[web.1]: goroutine 7 [running]:
2020-01-06T18:46:26.697585+00:00 app[web.1]: net/http.(*conn).serve.func1(0xc00008d180)
2020-01-06T18:46:26.697588+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/tmp/cache/go1.12.12/go/src/net/http/server.go:1769 +0x139
2020-01-06T18:46:26.697590+00:00 app[web.1]: panic(0x7e4280, 0xc00008a320)
2020-01-06T18:46:26.697592+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/tmp/cache/go1.12.12/go/src/runtime/panic.go:522 +0x1b5
2020-01-06T18:46:26.697595+00:00 app[web.1]: github.com/amunnelly/gowebappdatabase/dbconnect.runQuery(0xc0000946e0, 0x150, 0x0)
2020-01-06T18:46:26.697597+00:00 app[web.1]: /tmp/build_b7c9c282f9c067c1b5b5cede1994472d/dbconnect/connectdb.go:78 +0xff
2020-01-06T18:46:26.697599+00:00 app[web.1]: github.com/amunnelly/gowebappdatabase/dbconnect.PointsGdTableQuery(0xc0000946e0, 0x150, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
2020-01-06T18:46:26.697601+00:00 app[web.1]: /tmp/build_b7c9c282f9c067c1b5b5cede1994472d/dbconnect/connectdb.go:161 +0x64
2020-01-06T18:46:26.697604+00:00 app[web.1]: github.com/amunnelly/gowebappdatabase/routing.ServeHome(0x8db260, 0xc0001b2000, 0xc000128100)
2020-01-06T18:46:26.697606+00:00 app[web.1]: /tmp/build_b7c9c282f9c067c1b5b5cede1994472d/routing/routing.go:35 +0x1b5
2020-01-06T18:46:26.697608+00:00 app[web.1]: net/http.HandlerFunc.ServeHTTP(0x863ca0, 0x8db260, 0xc0001b2000, 0xc000128100)
2020-01-06T18:46:26.697611+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/tmp/cache/go1.12.12/go/src/net/http/server.go:1995 +0x44
2020-01-06T18:46:26.697614+00:00 app[web.1]: net/http.(*ServeMux).ServeHTTP(0xba17c0, 0x8db260, 0xc0001b2000, 0xc000128100)
2020-01-06T18:46:26.697616+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/tmp/cache/go1.12.12/go/src/net/http/server.go:2375 +0x1d6
2020-01-06T18:46:26.697618+00:00 app[web.1]: net/http.serverHandler.ServeHTTP(0xc000086c30, 0x8db260, 0xc0001b2000, 0xc000128100)
2020-01-06T18:46:26.697620+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/tmp/cache/go1.12.12/go/src/net/http/server.go:2774 +0xa8
2020-01-06T18:46:26.697622+00:00 app[web.1]: net/http.(*conn).serve(0xc00008d180, 0x8dbc20, 0xc0000206c0)
2020-01-06T18:46:26.697625+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/tmp/cache/go1.12.12/go/src/net/http/server.go:1878 +0x851
2020-01-06T18:46:26.697627+00:00 app[web.1]: created by net/http.(*Server).Serve
2020-01-06T18:46:26.697629+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/tmp/cache/go1.12.12/go/src/net/http/server.go:2884 +0x2f4
2020-01-06T18:46:26.697828+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=gowebappdatabase.herokuapp.com request_id=088bcdd0-e16f-40f9-a6a0-8d61f4bb5beb fwd="176.61.86.66" dyno=web.1 connect=5ms service=3ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
```

I'd love to be able to fix this. It's been wrecking my head all year.

Comment: Your handler panics (in `dbconnect.runQuery()`) and thus it writes nothing to the response. It looks your app can't access the database.

Comment: I'm sorry icza, I've only seen your comment now. Yes, you're completely correct. It was a DB authentication issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your posted code is not correct:

`s.ListenAndServe()` blocks current goroutine.

second `s.ListenAndServe()` is never called in your code

Your dbaccess code panics. Check how you handle all errors there:

> 2020-01-06T18:46:26.697592+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   /app/tmp/cache/go1.12.12/go/src/runtime/panic.go:522 +0x1b5
>   2020-01-06T18:46:26.697595+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   github.com/amunnelly/gowebappdatabase/dbconnect.runQuery(0xc0000946e0,
>   0x150, 0x0) 2020-01-06T18:46:26.697597+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   /tmp/build_b7c9c282f9c067c1b5b5cede1994472d/dbconnect/connectdb.go:78
>   +0xff 2020-01-06T18:46:26.697599+00:00 app[web.1]: github.com/amunnelly/gowebappdatabase/dbconnect.PointsGdTableQuery(0xc0000946e0,
>   0x150, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0) 2020-01-06T18:46:26.697601+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   /tmp/build_b7c9c282f9c067c1b5b5cede1994472d/dbconnect/connectdb.go:161
>   +0x64 2020-01-06T18:46:26.697604+00:00 app[web.1]: github.com/amunnelly/gowebappdatabase/routing.ServeHome(0x8db260,
>   0xc0001b2000, 0xc000128100) 2020-01-06T18:46:26.697606+00:00
>   app[web.1]:
>   /tmp/build_b7c9c282f9c067c1b5b5cede1994472d/routing/routing.go:35
>   +0x1b5

Comment: Thanks Dmitry, but I don't think that's it. I took out the `if else` loop and changed the call to `log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":"+os.Getenv("PORT"), nil))`, but I'm still getting the same error. I don't think it's a database problem because the call to the database works fine when I run the code locally. I'm completely baffled.

Comment: `I run the code locally` - locally you have different network settings. You have network issue accessing DB in place where you deployed app. That is what call stack tells.

Answer (score 0):

I’ve got this working. Here’s the solution, in the hope it spares someone else in the future.

The error, as Dmitry pointed out in his second answer, is with the connection to the postgresql database. What I tried to do was replicate my local database in heroku – that is, create a user with select privileges only, and then use those user details to query the database.

It turns out, however, that a [heroku postgres database comes complete with a default user](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql-credentials#the-default-credential). All you need to log in is the database url string, which is available as an environment variable. So I changed this

```
db, err := sql.Open("postgres", aStringWithUserDetails)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
    }
```

to this

```
db, err := sql.Open("postgres", os.Getenv("DATABASE_URL"))
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
    }
```

and Bob is now my uncle.